# How to obtain CSRF token from Laravel and pass it in a python script

Tags: php, python, laravel, csrf

I am using [oauth2-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/blob/master/docs/getting-started/laravel-5.md) to authenticate an api that exports data to a csv file. The documentation has this requirement.

> In order to make some the authorization and resource server work
>   correctly with Laravel5, remove the
>   `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` line from the `$middleware` array
>   and place it in the `$routeMiddleware` array like this:
>   `'csrf' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,`
>
> Note: remember to add the csrf middleware manually on any route where
>   it's appropriate.

The problem is my application is huge and I would rather not change all my other routes manually. So I came across [X-CSRF-TOKEN](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token) in the documentation.

My question is: How can I get the csrf token so that I can append it to my header parameter in Python? The docs say I can use the HTML tag `meta` but I am not using any HTML files for this task.

Also I can't use sessions because I do not need to login to access the API.

Comment: I could not find a solution to this, even after extensive googling. Instead I added the the routes that use oauth2 to the  `$except` array of the `VerifyCsrfToken` as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-excluding-uris)

Answer (score 3):

A better solution: You can  get a token with web **scraper** easily like BeautifulSoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(url) #url is create form 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('input'):
    token = link['value']
```

Of course, note that Laravel also generates a cookie per form. So you need to send cookies along with your post request.

```
jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
    jar.set('XSRF-TOKEN', r.cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'])
```

Now you can easily send your post request. For example, I'm sending a request for loggin

```
url_post = "http://localhost/login"    
data = {
        "_token": token,
        "email": "example@email.com",
        "password": "password"
    }


login_request = requests.post(url_post, data=data, cookies=jar)
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition of @Ali Sharifineyestani response, you should add the
`laravel_session`     cookie

```
jar.set('laravel_session', r.cookies['laravel_session'])
```